# How to Display the Birt Report in Same Jsp After calling through Button function by using java script or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, birt

I want to load the Birt Report After calling the function in div or iframe.
Tried in below manner :

```
         <html>
           <head>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                function myFunction() {
                **//var inn= "<birt\:viewer id=\"birtViewer\" reportDesign=\"test.rptdesign\" pattern=\"frameset\" height=\"500\" width=\"900\" format=\"html\"></birt\:viewer>"
                //alert(inn)
                //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = inn;**
                **var reporturl = "http://localhost:8080/Sample_Birt_viewer/frameset?__report=test.rptdesign&amp;sample=my+name";**
                alert("here");
                **$('#reportload').load(reporturl);**
                }
                </script>

                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
                <title>Insert title here</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me1</button>
                <div id="test">
                **<iframe id="reportload" name="myReport" height="300" width="1136" />**
                **<%-- <birt:viewer id="birtViewer" reportDesign="test.rptdesign"
                pattern="frameset"
                height="500"
                width="900"
                format="html"></birt:viewer> --%>
                </div>**

                </body>
                </html>
```

I tried in above manner it is not loading 
when loading the page if call directly in div it is working(like below), But i want to load through Java script or jquery, because i wand to show selected values as well as report in down.

```
<iframe id="reportload" name="myReport" height="300" width="1136" src="http://localhost:8080/Sample_Birt_viewer/frameset?__report=test.rptdesign&amp;sample=my+parameter" />
                <birt:viewer id="birtViewer" reportDesign="test.rptdesign"
                pattern="frameset"
                height="500"
                width="900"
                format="html"></birt:viewer>
```

How can I over come above problem?

Comment: is `http://localhost:8080/` the same host that the page is loaded from?

Comment: I don't think you want to use `$('#reportload').load(reporturl);` to target an iframe ... perhaps make `iframe id="reportload"` a `div` instead

Comment: i approach in below manner it is working fine    <div id="test"></div> in script function i used this document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"http://localhost:8080/Sample_Birt_viewer/frameset?__report=test.rptdesign&amp;sample=my+parameter\" height=400 width=700></iframe>"

Comment: But  I have to remove the BIRT Report Viewer in that window or replace with other name. How can i do that one?